# How to reset duplex settings for my printers in Fineprint?

Tags: reset, duplex, fineprint

When I print using Fineprint duplex feature for the first time with printer P1, Fineprint launch a wizard which helps me to set up the target printer. After a while, I want to re-config the duplex setting for target printer but I don't know how to.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the target printer and go to its Advance settings and fire the Wizard button. See the red arrow in my below screenshot.

Hope that helps!

[image]